# Notepad++: block comment not working

Tags: editor, notepad++

I am running Notepad++ 5.8.5 on Windows 7, editing Perl programs.
I would like to comment out a block of text lines (and later, perhaps, uncomment it).

None of the following  works:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, 

selecting the block of lines and going to the menu: edit-> Comment/Uncomment -> Block Comment

none of the above has any effect.

What to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not try updating to a newer version? That's horribly out of date (a year old).

Comment: I upgraded to current version, tried it and it worked. Thank you, @Oesor. By the way, one year old software is not that "horrible", and shouldn't have simple bugs.

Comment: Terrible answer when you have the current version and it still does not work. v 7.5.3

Comment: Yeah, newer version is not working either. Update didn't fix.

Answer (score 10):

Is NP++ interpreting your file as Perl or plain text?

If NP++ is treating your file as plain text, then language specific things like that won't work.

You may want to double-check that as described [here](http://allthingsmarked.com/2009/07/29/associate-file-extensions-with-specific-languages-in-notepad-plus-plus/).

Answer (score 4):

Define your own language to match to the file extension, in your case it is: txt
and then define any comment style you want. Then close and open NP++ again. Enjoy!

Path:  Language--->Define your Language --> Comments & Number tab
Hank Wei