# Notepad++ mark multiple lines with # at the beginning

Tags: notepad++

I would like to know if there is a way to mark multiple lines in notpad++ and add to all of them # at the beginning in order to mark them as a comment,|I didn't find an answer in the exists posts.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838875/notepad-block-comment-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Commenting (or 'marking') multiple lines is language dependent and is done by selecting the lines and clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>:

For example:

- Python will use the `#` letter.
- C it will use `//`.

Removing those markings is done in the same way - using selection and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Please note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is for single line comments. If you want to comment out multiple lines at once (block comment), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and for uncommenting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Alternatively you can find all these commands under the `Edit` > `Comment/Uncomment` menu.

Comment: Thanks,
I changed the language to python and then I saw the # sign.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, please consider accepting the answer if it works for you, and welcome to stackoverflow :)